# How many days have elapsed since the Battle of Winterfell?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones - S08E04: The Last of the Starks*, we see the aftermath of the Battle of Winterfell. The fallen heroes are laid to rest, then a big feast to celebrate life, then the battle plan to defeat Cersei & then they depart from Winterfell.

Exactly how many days have elapsed since the battle till the time Daenerys departs to Dragonstone?

On the day following the Long Night, they burn all the dead. Then the same night they have a feast. The next day, Dany & Jon make the battle plan for Cersei. Then they all depart with their armies.

But during the battle, lot of damage was done to Winterfell. It was burning & destroyed all over. But yet today we see everything has been repaired. The rooms are repaired, the courtyard has been repaired.

It would take a minimum a month to repair the damage.

So, how much time elapsed?

Comment: Don't try to think too much about timeframes in this show, especially the later seasons with no book source to draw from yet. The producers don't really care about that anymore, if they ever did.

Comment: Not only travel time - everyone just seems to be able to teleport instantly now... that actually is the best explanation, sadly, for most of the recent "ambushes".

Comment: @Annatar  Well, *one* guy seems to be able to teleport himself and his entire fleet at will, at least.

Answer (score 6):

*Spoilers for S08E04 below, obviously. Read at your own risk.*

---

At what part of the episode?

We can't truly know, but we can assume a reasonable amount of time between each event.

- Burning of the dead: ~12 hours after Night Kings's Death
- Celebration feast: ~24 hours after Night Kings's Death
- First War council: ~1-3 days after Night Kings's Death
- Army leaving Winterfell: ~2-5 days after Night Kings's Death
- Death of Rhaegal: ~1-2 weeks after Night Kings's Death
- Death of Missandei: ~2-3 weeks after Night Kings's Death

Each of these events is separated by a hard cut for all POV characters, allowing for arbitrary amounts of time between them. This is the magic that allowed Ned to get all the way down the Kingsroad (a month long journey) in a single episode (S01E02). This differs from reality-bending time-travel/teleportation like Daenerys rescuing Jon and Co from the Lake Battle, because in that instance, we didn't have a hard cut, that whole sequence was implicitly stated to have occurred in however long it takes for a human to die from hypothermia. If, when Tyrion had been talking at Cersei, he had said something like "we killed the Night King three days ago and can melt you at will, please give up", then we would have time problems. But since the show didn't specify a timeline, we can allow that the mundane travel and general boring day to day events happened out of sight whenever the scene cut.

We do know that the events of S08E04 were accelerated because Sansa was complaining about rushing the army and not giving them time to recuperate. We know that the "peace talks" where Missandei died happened in under a month, because Jon (who was traveling the Kingsroad) wasn't there yet. Also, we saw the repairs of Winterfell underway in the episode, so we know they were working on it. No reason from a storytelling point of view to give us a play-by-play on that progress.

Comment: The journey from Winterfell to Kingslanding took four weeks in book and season 1

Comment: @user1129682 What's your point? That was a famously lazy king traveling with women and a general party atmosphere, not a navy heading out for war.

Comment: @AzorAhai Tyrion says to (I think) Varys that "it could be a fortnight" before Jon arrives. So the four weeks were either notably quick, or it hasn't been that long that the ground army left Winterfell.

Comment: @user1129682 Daenerys didn't take the Kingsroad, so the 4-weeks doesn't apply to her. She took the ships, which is why she was significantly faster at getting south.

Comment: @amflare Well observed! We are trying to piece together how much "significantly" is in this case. I would assume a jolly king Robert on vacation reunited with his best friend Ned Stark moves as fast as a northern army, which means about 4 weeks in total. Tyrion says Jon is about a Fortnight away. If Dany and Jon left Winterfell on the same day, Dany was about two weeks faster. IMO this is unrealistic because Winterfell has no harbor. I'd expect Jons army moves a lot slower b/c Winter is here. But I suppose both are moving at exactly plot miles an hour.

Comment: @user And? They were going to hole up in Dragonstone until the army arrived, they just got ambushed because apparently Daenerys is blind